# Dialog box basics

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with dialog box basics, and i have looked this up, but i have found nothing on it. What is the `JOptionPane` for the X in the top right of the GUI? When i click it, it carries on running the script. i know that it requires an `System.exit(0);
This is what i have so far:

```
int dialogButton= JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION;
int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "", "Info",dialogButton);
if(dialogResult==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    //Code for YES Button Clicked
} else if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);
} else if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("message");
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Title");
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.show();
```

You can set the default close operation of the dialog box.